# Adding a value to existing system variable (powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, system-variable

```
[Enviroment]::SetEnviromentVariable("Path", "d:/test/bin;c:/test", "Machine"
```

If the variable already exists with other values in it; how can I adjust this script to not overwrite existing entries. While adding the new additional values?

Answer (score 0):

When i need to add software to env path using powershell, i use this:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")+";<YOUR_PATH_HERE>", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

But i dont know if efficient, pretty sure a better way exist.

Comment: This will duplicate the data if it's already there.

Comment: Yes before running this command, in my script i test if my path are in the path environment variable.

But, maybe i'm wrong, but the initial question are "How to add a value to existing system variable", and this command, create this behavior.

If you have a better answer, don't hesitate to share it, i would be interested.